# Susy: Push(pre) and Pull(

Tags: layout, sass, susy-compass

The following code places my *sidebar-first* one column off the left of the screen.

```
.has-sidebar-first {
.l-content {
  @include span-columns(15 omega, 16); // Span 15 out of 16 columns.
  @include push(1, 16);  // Push element by adding 1 out of 16 columns of left margin.
}
.l-region--sidebar-first {
  @include span-columns(1, 16); // Span 1 out of 16 columns.
  @include pull(1, 16); // Pull element by adding 15 out of 16 columns of negative left margin.      
}
```

}

The *sidebar-first* should take up the first column and content should take up the next 15.
I have had *pull* set 1 through to 16 but it is either out of place or disappears entirely.
[image: layout]

Any suggestion?

**Update1**: Here is the full scss layout(including the suggestion from Eric Meyer (the man himself!) places the *sidebar-first* further off page to the left. It appears to be offpage by the same width as the *l-content* .

```
@import "susy";

// Susy Variables

// Set consistent vertical and horizontal spacing units.
$vert-spacing-unit: 20px;
$horz-spacing-unit: 1em;

// Define Susy grid variables mobile first.
$total-columns: 4;
$column-width: 4em;
$gutter-width: $horz-spacing-unit;
$grid-padding: 5px;

$container-style: magic;
$container-width: 1200px;

// Susy Media Layouts @see http://susy.oddbird.net/guides/reference/#ref-media-layouts
$tab: 44em 12; // At 44em use 12 columns.
$desk: 70em 16; // At 70em use 16 columns.

.l-header,
.l-main,
.l-footer {
  @include container; // Define these elements as the grid containers.
  margin-bottom: $vert-spacing-unit;
}

.l-region--highlighted,
.l-region--help,
.l-region--sidebar-first,
.l-region--sidebar-second {
  margin-bottom: $vert-spacing-unit;
}

@include at-breakpoint($tab) { // At a given Susy Media Layout, use a given amount of columns.
  .l-header,
  .l-main,
  .l-footer {
    @include set-container-width; // Reset only the container width (elements have already been declared as containers).
  }

  .l-branding {
    @include span-columns(4, 12); // Span 4 out of 12 columns.
  }
  .l-region--header{
    @include span-columns(8 omega, 12); // Span the last (omega) 8 columns of 12.
  }
  .l-region--navigation {
    clear: both;
  }

  .has-sidebar-first,
  .has-sidebar-second,
  .has-two-sidebars {
    .l-content {
      @include span-columns(7, 12); // Span 7 out of 12 columns.
      @include push(1, 12);  // Push element by adding 1 out of 12 columns of left margin.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-first, {
      @include span-columns(1, 12); // Span the 1 columns of 12.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-second {
      @include span-columns(4 omega, 12); // Span the last (omega) 4 columns of 12.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-first {
      @include pull(8, 12); // Pull element by adding 8 out of 12 columns of negative left margin.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-second {
      clear: right;
    }
  }
}

@include at-breakpoint($desk) {
  .l-header,
  .l-main,
  .l-footer {
    @include set-container-width; // Reset only the container width (elements have already been declared as containers).
  }

  .l-branding {
    @include span-columns(6, 16); // Span 6 out of 16 columns.
  }
  .l-region--header{
    @include span-columns(10 omega, 16); // Span the last (omega) 10 columns of 16.
  }

  .has-sidebar-first {
    .l-content {
      @include span-columns(15 omega, 16); // Span 15 out of 16 columns.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-first {
      @include span-columns(1, 16); // Span 1 out of 16 columns.
    }
  }
  .has-sidebar-second {
    .l-content {
      @include span-columns(12, 16); // Span 12 out of 16 columns.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-second {
      @include span-columns(4 omega, 16); // Span the last (omega) 4 columns of 16.
      clear: none;
    }
  }

  .has-two-sidebars {
    .l-content {
      @include span-columns(10, 16); // Span 10 out of 16 columns.
      @include push(1, 16);  // Push element by adding 1 out of 16 columns of left margin.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-first {
      @include span-columns(1, 16); // Span 1 out of 16 columns.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-second {
      @include span-columns(5, 16); // Span 5 out of 16 columns.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-first {
      @include pull(11, 16); // Pull element by adding 11 out of 16 columns of negative left margin.
    }
    .l-region--sidebar-second {
      @include omega; // This element spans the last (omega) column.
      clear: none;
    }
  }
}
```

*.has-two-sidebars* is working as desired. I am only hoping to fix *.has-sidebar-first* when *@include at-breakpoint($desk)* . If there is something inherently wrong with how it is set up then I will have to change the lot but I am hoping to simply change the the layout when viewed on a desktop where the is no sidebar second.

Thanks

**Update 2**
Following the suggestion to add `margin-left: 0;` here is it added.

```
.has-sidebar-first {
.l-content {
  @include span-columns(15 omega, 16); // Span 15 out of 16 columns.
}
.l-region--sidebar-first {
  @include span-columns(1, 16); // Span 1 out of 16 columns.
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

}

While this now aligns the 'side-first' to the correct column, it appears below the content, as per the picture:
[image: Displaced sidebar]
The rest of the code is the same. The two sidebar option still displays correctly.
Any suggestions?

**Solution:**
As per Eric's suggestion I needed to clear and previously declared push and pulls. So the correct code is:

```
.has-sidebar-first {
.l-content {
  @include span-columns(15 omega, 16); // Span 15 out of 16 columns.
  margin-left: 0;
}
.l-region--sidebar-first {
  @include span-columns(1, 16); // Span 1 out of 16 columns.
  margin-left: 0;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get rid of both the `push` and the `pull`. Neither one is needed. Your `omega` item is floated right, and the other item is floated left, so both will fall perfectly into place without needing any push/pull help.

**update**:

You have a pull set on `.l-region--sidebar-first` at one of the smaller breakpoints, which is still being applied at the larger breakpoint. You just need to set `margin-left` to `0` at the `$desk` breakpoint.

Comment: thank you for the reply Eric, and all the time you have put into Susy. I tried removing the push and pull but is doesn't display correctly. I have update to question which now includes the full scss. Does anything pop to mind as a quick fix?

Comment: I have added the margin-left 0 and updated the question. Thanks

Comment: Yep, you still have a `push` on the content, pushing it over 1 of 12. You may have other things like that, which I'm missing. The point is: if you add things earlier in the cascade, you have to remove them later if you don't still need them.

Comment: I added another `margin-left` `0` this time to the content and all sorted. Thank you for help out and being so patient with me!